# The best cloud server solution for android application to automatically upload files

Tags: java, android, cloud

I have created an application that stores information into a text file and saves it to the SD card on an android phone. However I am having problems making the application upload these files to a cloud server automatically. Currently I am working on a Google drive solution but I cannot seem to get this to work. I was just wondering if there were other cloud servers or online storage solutions I could use which would be fairly straight forward to setup?

I am currently using Google’s configured Eclipse as a developing environment if this helps.

Comment: Post your relevant code and error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Drive and Dropbox could be good options. Both need to generate a token, what I don't like since you have to generate a new one everytime you deploy the app, but it is a good free alternative -they also provide a paid tier.

One of the best alternatives for cloud storage is in my opinion Amazon S3, where you don't need to create a token and just need your credentials. An app example using Amazon S3 could be find [here](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart). Another good point is that you can choose the physical location of your "bucket" so you could avoid network latency.